# How can I use Django inline formset with Bootstrap-select plugin?

Tags: django, django-templates, bootstrap-select, inline-formset

I've been trying to use the Django inline formset with the bootstrap-select plugin from here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ and every other thing works perfectly, I'm able to successfully call the plugin on another two selects that I have in my form and I'm using the inline formset to add new authors on my book. When i put the "selectpicker" class, it only works once, when the page is loaded, but when I press the button to add more authors, the select field is not loaded.

So I have a question... can I use the two together? If yes, how? If not, is there any workaround to be able to search in a selection field?

Bellow is a image to how my form looks when i press the big green "Add" button at the end of the form.
[image: my form, showing the problem with the author inline formset]

You can see that there is only two fields, one less than the first one.

If any code is needed, please let me know and i will add right away.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are my codes, as asked by Chris:

My template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
  {% load static %}
  <form method="POST" class="form" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    [other fields]
    ...

    <!-- HERE I HAVE MY TWO OTHER SELECT FIELDS WHICH WORK PERFECTLY -->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label>Editora do Livro:</label>
              {{ form.editora_cod_editora|add_class:"selectpicker form-control"|attr:"data-live-search='true'" }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label>Categoria do Livro:</label>
              {{form.categoria_cod_categoria|add_class:"selectpicker form-control"|attr:"data-live-search='true'" }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- HERE START MY ONLINE FORM, AS SHOWS THE PRINT -->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <hr>
        <h4>Adicionar Autor</h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group bg-light rounded ">
        {{ autor_livro.management_form }}
          {% for form in autor_livro.forms %}
            <div class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row m-5 inline-form">
              {{ form.autor_cod_autor|add_class:"selectpicker form-control"|attr:"data-live-search='true'" }}
              {{ form.ordinal_autorlivro|add_class:"form-control" }}
              {{ form.autor_funcao|add_class:"form-control" }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-outline-primary btn float-right">Salvar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    {% block scripts %}
      <!-- HERE I HAVE MY SCRIPT THAT MAKES THE INLINE FORM WORK WITH THAT PLUGIN -->
      <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
          addText: 'Adicionar Autor',
          deleteText: 'Remover',
          prefix: 'autorlivro_set'
        });
      </script>
    {% endblock %}
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think posting your html template could be helpful

Comment: I posted my template, do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the behaviour of the `bootstrap-select` plugin. You are activating it by using the class "selectpicker". After loading the page some javascript magic takes the elements with the class `selectpicker` and creates the widget you see. The "select" you now see is not your original `<select>` but an auxillary widget, your `<select>` is still there but hidden from your view.

Now when you add another form the javascript magic is not called again, so that you get a new form where your `<select>` is hidden somewhere from the user's eyes.

In order to get it rendered nicely again you need to run the required javascript after you have added a new form. `django-dynamic-formset` provides an option called `added` allowing you define a function which is called after the new form has been added. Form more details see the formset options [here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst).

So define the function and call it after adding a form. In your case your script could look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var activate_select = function(row){
        row.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    };

    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Adicionar Autor',
        deleteText: 'Remover',
        prefix: 'autorlivro_set,
        added: activate_select
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: No probs, was a pleasure